Invoke logout function when device's network changes (i.e. connect to other wifi network or so)
I’m trying to call a logout function when the network changes in my React application. However, as soon as I log in, my useEffect hook automatically triggers, causing an unintended logout, even though the network hasn't actually changed. I’d like the logout function to be called only when there’s a genuine network change (such as a disconnect or reconnect event), not on minor variations or when the app initially loads.
I am testing this on chrome browser. I am using navigator api in my useEffect with event listener in my App.jsx file but its not working out. It randomly logs out the user.
const { handleLogout } = useLogout()

  const whenUserIsIdle = () => {
    if (isUserAuthenticated)
      handleLogout()
  }

  useIdleTimer({
    onIdle: whenUserIsIdle,
    timeout: 300000, //5 minutes
    throttle: 500, // checks after 500ms
  });
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleNetworkChange = () => {
      console.log('connection network change effect',connection);
      if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
        const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;

        // Perform a condition check to prevent unnecessary logouts
        if (connection && connection.downlink > 0) { // for example, checking if downlink speed is above 0
          handleLogout();
        }
      }
    };

    const connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
    if (connection) {
      connection.addEventListener('change', handleNetworkChange);
    }

    return () => {
      if (connection) {
        connection.removeEventListener('change', handleNetworkChange);
      }
    };
  }, [handleLogout]);

my custom logout hook:
const useLogout = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleNavigateToRoot = useNavigatetoRoot();


    // Define the function to handle successful logout
    const onSuccessfullLogout = (response) => {
        handleNavigateToRoot()
    };

    // Get mutate function from the usePostDataToServer hook
    const { mutate } = usePostDataToServer({
        onPostReqSuccess: onSuccessfullLogout,
        dispatch,
    });

    // Define a function to handle logout
    const handleLogout = () => {
        const API_URL = `${BASE_URL}${ENDPOINTS.LOGOUT}`;
        mutate({ API_URL, dispatch });
    };

    return { handleLogout };
};

export default useLogout;


I know that chrumiom based browsers dominate ... but there's a hell of a lot of apple users too (won't mention mozilla) ... navigator.connection is chrumiom only, mozConnection/webkitConnection seems to be something you hope exists, but doesn't seem to have ever existed

so what should i do? if it works on chromium based browser that will be fine too.
